# Render CVImageBufferRef to the screen iOS 8

Tags: ios8, rendering

How do I Render CVImageBufferRef to the screen iOS 8 ?

I have a decoded image buffer, I want to display it on the screen

Answer (score 0):

Hope this sample application will help you in rendering the decoded images in iOS..

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLCameraRipple/Introduction/Intro.html

If you have the encoded frames from the elementary stream , pass the data to AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer , which will decode and display your images.